# Regular expression for javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract GTM-5CMF3P from given script ..with the help of regular expression ?? can some one help

```
oogletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
 })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-5CMF3P');</scr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `value`
- Regular Expression: `'dataLayer','(.+?)'\);`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer extracted value as `${value}` or `${__V(value)}` where required.

You can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to test your regular expressions against real response:

[image: View Results Tree]

Reference Material:

- [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter's User Manual
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1743642)